# AppDelegate.m and ViewController.h files have turned red in my xcode project navigator

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I reopened my xcode project and the `AppDelegate.h` and `ViewController.m` files are red. The titles are there but they seem to be empty. Does anyone know how to retrieve these files, or are they lost? I had a decent amount of code in there so I was hoping not. I'm new to this so any basic steps type help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if you have deleted it by mistake. Check the physical folder to make sure the file is there. If it is there, remove the red links from Xcode and try adding it again.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "check the physical folder"? How would I do that? Right now there is just a red title in the navigator which normally I could click on and it brings up the code to the right. However if I click it now it does nothing.

Comment: I meant the finder window where your project is kept. Can you check in the finder window where the project is saved.

Comment: what if it is not in the physical folder?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the files its looking for are not in the same location as they were the last time you opened the project.  Find the files in question, add them back to your project, and delete the red links.